# Ionic translation error

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic

No entiendo por qué cuando ingreso este código obtengo varios errores en la función HttpLoaderFactory: Use const o constructores de clases en lugar de funciones con nombre eslint(prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions) + El nombre de la función HttpLoaderFactory debe coincidir con uno de los siguientes formatos: camelCase eslint @typescript-eslint/naming-convention). Previamente ingresé estos comandos en el repositorio:
npm install @ngx-translate/core --save
npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader --save

````
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  TranslateModule,
  TranslateLoader,
  TranslateService,
} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO (spanish), please translate your question, otherwise, it'll be closed.

Comment: Hi, this is the Spanish Ver. of StackOverflow; so, you need to translate your question into spanish, otherwise this question will be close.

Comment: Buen día, has publicado tu pregunta en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español, la pregunta está en un idioma que no es el oficial en este sitio y por lo tanto puede ser cerrada o votada negativamente. Te recomiendo que leas la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Puedes traducir tu pregunta o publicarla en el sitio de Stack Overflow en inglés